# std::cin - can you have one input put into two different variables?

Tags: c++, oop, stdin

Hi I am trying to read input from the user once and then pass this value into two different types of variables is this possible?

I need the value to be passed into an integer variable which is required for calculations and also a string so I can add the data to the formatted date which is a string variable.

Here is he code which I have tried which doesn't work.

```
cin >> daymonth,dayofmonth;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I am programming in OOP if this is of any relevance.

Comment: `cin >> daymonth >> dayofmonth`

Comment: Thanks but I have tried this and it needs two inputs, I only want to ask for one.

Comment: Which one is the string and which one is the integer??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try copying / assignment:

```
cin >> daymonth;
dayofmonth = daymonth;
```

In the performance of your program, using multiple lines or multiple statements is negligible.

Concentrate on making the program work correctly and robustly.

**Edit 1:  dayofmonth is a string.**

```
cin >> dayofmonth;
istringstream s(dayofmonth);
s >> daymonth;
```

Comment: Please edit your question with the variable types.  I assumed both variables were of the same type.

Comment: That's a bit overkill: `daymonth = std::stoi(dayofmonth);` will do.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot read into two variables simultaneously. The type of variable that you read into determines how far to read. For example, reading into a string stops at white space while reading into an integer stops at the first non-integer character. Reading into two variables simultaneously would make it ambiguous where the next reading operation starts.

Read into an integer and then convert the integer to a string (e.g. using [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string)).

Comment: Thanks, this was an option I was considering although I tried to_string which didn't work. code:daymonth to_string(dayofmonth)

Comment: @LukeMills Compile with the option `-std=c++11` and it should be `daymonth = to_string(dayofmonth)` (you forgot the `=`).

Answer (score 0):

You can overload `<<`

```
#include<sstream>
//..
class X{

    int daymonth;
    std::string dayofmonth;

    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, X& m)
    {

        is >> m.daymonth;
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << m.daymonth;
        m.dayofmonth = ss.str();
        return is;
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const X& m)
    {
        return os << m.daymonth << ":" << m.dayofmonth;

    }
};
```

And then

```
 X x;  
 std::cin >> x;
 std::cout << x;
```